# How to create a background color behind transparent PNG with non-standard shape?

Tags: html, css, png

I'm trying to create some custom map markers with a numbered label. These markers could be any different color and number so I am hoping to do it in pure **CSS** with a transparent **PNG** of the marker outline. Te issue I'm running into is the background-color I set on my DIV fills a rectangular area, but I need it to just fill in the internal area within the borders of my marker outline. I posted a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsws73xo/) that shows what I mean - I'm using a rudimentary star icon for simplicity but in actuality the marker I intend to use is more complex with many intersections, angles etc. What is the best way to create dynamic markers with variable background colors, short of creating every possibility in a **PNG** sprite?

From the JSFiddle:

```
background-color:red;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64...)
```

Comment: You need to make those css r svg only then apply background-color for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As C-link Nepal commented, you need svg. It's little bit trickier to create but it will solve your problem.

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
<path style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:3;fill-rule:nonzero;"  
    d="
        M 100.000 70.000
        L 131.153 92.878
        L 119.021 56.180
        L 150.406 33.622
        L 111.756 33.820
        L 100.000 3.000
        L 88.244 33.820
        L 49.594 33.622
        L 80.979 56.180
        L 68.847 92.878
        L 100.000 70.000"
 />
```

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frnjotxp/) for 'star' example.